# App Center REST API / Push - Custom Users and Custom Properties

Tags: rest, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center-push

I'm using App Center Push - works great.  I'm sending via the user list (user_ids_target).

I'm using Xamarin Forms - so the user could be on either iOS or Android (or both).  I was hoping to be able to query the App Center api via Rest to get a list of these users (from SetUserId - not testers/team members).

Does anyone know how to get a list of 'application' users for each app?

Same with Custom Properties.  I see an end point to get what custom properties are configured - but not the values for the application user / device.

Answer (score 0):

you could refer to [App Center Client](https://openapi.appcenter.ms/#/distribute/devices_listCsvFormat)

and the api maybe is what you want,it will returns all devices associated with the given distribution group:

> /v0.1/apps/{owner_name}/{app_name}/distribution_groups/{distribution_group_name}/devices/download_devices_list

Comment: It seems like a distribution group is something setup for testers?  If so, what I'm looking for is for users of the application - identified from SetUserId

Comment: You mean as a user and not as a developer to get the users list ?

Comment: Not related to distribution.  Users of the application - within Xamarin Forms I call SetUserId to a custom ID (unique to the app).  I am looking at how to query that information from the API